# Logstash conf file not working, what's wrong with the syntax?

Tags: elasticsearch, windows-server-2008, logstash

What about the .conf file below is incorrect that would cause logstash to not index and store the log file for elasticsearch? I'm running kibana/elasticsearch/logstash all on the same windows server(2008 R2) using IIS.

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["c:\logs\bb-auth.txt"]
    start_position => beginning
    type = "bb_authentication"
  }
}

output {
stdout { }
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
  }
}
```

I'm just trying to start small before I get ahead of myself and using just one file. But this doesn't even seem to work and I've restarted the service each time I've made a change to the file.

Comment: Can you start with --verbose or --debug and see if there is something interesting in the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this lira issue you can try the following path:

https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-430

C:/logs/bb-auth.txt

Comment: Good call, I will try that tomorrow when I get to work.

Answer (score 2):

Run Logstash by hand with `--configtest` to check the syntax of a config file. Not positive on how to do this on Windows, but I suspect it's something like `java c:\some\path\to\logstash\bin\logstash -f c:\path\to\configfile.conf --configtest`

Configtest should give you a clue where in the file something is wrong.

When I run that though configtest, it shows that you should be using `type => "bb_authentication"` not `type = "bb_authentication"`